# Group JS Array of items into an 'Other' Group based on value

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create some useful pie chart data however when viewing some info with random extras the pie chart doesn't become useful.

e.g.:

```
0: {label: "Chinese", count: 1, type: "language"}
1: {label: "Czech", count: 1, type: "language"}
2: {label: "Dutch", count: 1, type: "language"}
3: {label: "English", count: 747, type: "language"}
4: {label: "French", count: 4, type: "language"}
5: {label: "German", count: 3, type: "language"}
6: {label: "Italian", count: 4, type: "language"}
7: {label: "Korean", count: 1, type: "language"}
8: {label: "Russian", count: 5, type: "language"}
9: {label: "Spanish", count: 4, type: "language"}
```

The above you can see that English is the main language so what i wanted to do is if a count < 5 for example group all those items into an 'Other' label..so the resulting array would be

```
0: {label: "English", count: 747, type: "language"}
1: {label: "Other", count: 19, type: "language"}
```

Can someone help how to do this in JS ?

My Try:

```
  const getLanguageData = () => {
    let arr = metricsPies.filter((x) => {
      return x.type === 'language';
    });

    let others = [
      {
        label: 'Others',
        count: arr
          .filter((x) => {
            return x.count < 10;
          })
          .reduce(function (a, b) {
            return a + b['count'];
          }, 0),
        type: 'language',
      },
    ];

    let main = arr.filter((x) => {
      return x.count >= 10;
    });

    return main.concat(others);
  };
```

Comment: please add your try.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array to an object, adding `count` value to the `Other` object if it exists, or creating one if it doesn't exists:

```js
const arr = [{"label":"Chinese","count":1,"type":"language"},{"label":"Czech","count":1,"type":"language"},{"label":"Dutch","count":1,"type":"language"},{"label":"English","count":747,"type":"language"},{"label":"French","count":4,"type":"language"},{"label":"German","count":3,"type":"language"},{"label":"Italian","count":4,"type":"language"},{"label":"Korean","count":1,"type":"language"},{"label":"Russian","count":5,"type":"language"},{"label":"Spanish","count":4,"type":"language"}]

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const label = o.count < 5 ? 'Other' : o.label
  
  if(!acc[label]) acc[label] = { ...o, label }
  else acc[label].count += o.count
  
  return acc
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

You can use array destructuring if you want the `Other` object to always be at the end of the array:

```js
const arr = [{"label":"Chinese","count":1,"type":"language"},{"label":"Czech","count":1,"type":"language"},{"label":"Dutch","count":1,"type":"language"},{"label":"English","count":747,"type":"language"},{"label":"French","count":4,"type":"language"},{"label":"German","count":3,"type":"language"},{"label":"Italian","count":4,"type":"language"},{"label":"Korean","count":1,"type":"language"},{"label":"Russian","count":5,"type":"language"},{"label":"Spanish","count":4,"type":"language"}]

const { Other, ...rest } = arr.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const label = o.count < 5 ? 'Other' : o.label
  
  if(!acc[label]) acc[label] = { ...o, label }
  else acc[label].count += o.count
  
  return acc
}, {})

const languages = Object.values(rest)

const result = Other ? [...languages, Other] : languages

console.log(result)
```